# Spring RESTFul Client – RestTemplate

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I'm using `Resttemplate class` to get `all User` object. But when i run Main in Client then occur error, please let me know how fix it ???

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of
>   edu.java.spring.service.user.model.User out of START_ARRAY token  at
>   [Source:
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@7d70d1b1;
>   line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of edu.java.spring.service.user.model.User out of
>   START_ARRAY token  at [Source:
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@7d70d1b1;
>   line: 1, column: 1]   at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:220)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:502)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:239)
>     at
>   edu.java.spring.service.client.RestClientTest.getUsers(RestClientTest.java:57)
>     at
>   edu.java.spring.service.client.RestClientTest.main(RestClientTest.java:40)
>   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can
>   not deserialize instance of edu.java.spring.service.user.model.User
>   out of START_ARRAY token  at [Source:
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@7d70d1b1;
>   line: 1, column: 1]

Here file `RestClientTest.java`

```
public class RestClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        List<User> users = getUsers();
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Rest Response" + loadUser(users.get(i).getUserName()));
        }

    }
    public static List<User> getUsers(){
        String uri = new String("http://localhost:8080/rest/user/list");
        RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
        return (List<User>) rt.getForObject(uri,User.class);
    }
```

Here file `UserRestServiceController.java`

```
@Controller
public class UserRestServiceController {
    @Autowired
    public  UserDao userDao;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/user/list", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<User> getUsers(){
        return userDao.listUsers();
    }
```

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: @duffymo, you don't see my project done like your link

Comment: It's a working example. Might show you what you did wrong.

Comment: I learn using resttemplate in `http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-restful/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/ ` but really don't understand my project wrong

Comment: We see that. Try something else.

Answer (score 3):

I think the rest method is sending you back the `List<User>` objects but you are trying to parse it using `User.class` in following code : `rt.getForObject(uri,User.class);`. Try something like `rt.getForObject(uri,List.class);`.

Comment: i have tried with your way, but occur new error:`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to edu.java.spring.service.user.model.User
 at edu.java.spring.service.client.RestClientTest.main(RestClientTest.java:33)`